# Unix-like path converted to json with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, computer-science, mongoose-schema

I'm migrating from python to javascript. So now, I'm working on a react project where I need to convert some unix-like path to json. Actually, there aren't folders, they're list of categories joined by "/".
Here is what I have:

- Category Model holds the categories and the slug play as categories list joined by "/"

```js
const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    slug: { type: String, unique: true }, // Repr the route
    image: { type: String },
    topLevel: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

One representation of a category is like this:

```json
{
  name: "embedded",
  slug: "/electronics/embedded",
  image: "/some/image.png",
  topLevel: "electronics",
  description: "This is a brief description."
}
```

Now what I want is when I have a list of object like this

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "embedded",
    slug: "/electronics/embedded",
    image: "/some/image.png",
    topLevel: "electronics",
    description: "This is a brief description."
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:"electonics",
    slug:"/electronics",
    topLevel: "electronics",
    image: "/some/image.png",
    description: "..."
  },
  {
    id: 3, 
    name: "house",
    slug: "/house",
    topLevel: "house",
    image: "/some/image.png",
    description: "...",
  }
]
```

to end up having from the slug which are the unix-like paths as:

```json
[
  {
     id: 2,
     node: "electronics",
     children: [{
       id: 1,
       node: "embedded",
       children: [],
     }],
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     node: "house",
     children: []
   },
]
```

This is what I'm really struggling trying to have. If someone can help, you are more than welcome.

Comment: "Really struggling" meaning you can't find a tree unflattening algorithm, or your implementation of tree unflattening doesn't work? In the latter case, please post the problematic code.

Comment: Actually, I tried but I got it all wrong so it means that I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on yesterday's comment on whether I've tried something yet or not, I have basically come up with something but still not perfect because I didn't walk deep the whole tree.
Based on the input data and the type of output I want to have, this is my first trial:

```
function listToTree(list) {
    var node,
        i,
        roots = [];

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        node = list[i];
        var slugList = node.slug.split("/").filter((x) => x !== "");
        var children = [];

        if (slugList.length > 1) {
            var parent = slugList.shift();
            var parentNode = {
                node: parent,
                id: node.id,
                children: [],
            };
            roots.push(parentNode);
            for (var j = 0; j < slugList.length; j++) {
                var child = {
                    id: node.id,
                    node: slugList[j],
                    children: [],
                };
                children.push(child);
            }
            roots[i].children = [...children];
        } else {
            roots.push({
                node: node.topLevel,
                id: node.id,
                children: [],
            });
        }
    }
    return roots;
}
```

The output:

```
const roots = listToTree(exampleData);
console.log(roots[0]);

{
  node: 'electronics',
  id: 1,
  children: [ { id: 1, node: 'embedded', children: [] } ]
}
```

So, I still need some help and to be honest this answer here, not yet perfect, was inspired by the answered made by Halcyon in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017869/build-tree-array-from-flat-array-in-javascript)